# Node.js checkbox controller

Tags: node.js, mongoose

If user doesn't accept the term policy checkbox, I don't want mongoose and node.js to register this user in server side.

**Front end checkbox**

```
<div className="mb-3 form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" className="form-check-input register-input" name="registerCheckbox" id="exampleCheck1" onChange={e => this.checkController(e)} />
      <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="exampleCheck1">I agree the non-existing terms of use.</label>
</div>
```

**Server side and what I did**

```
const User = require('../Models/User')
const errHandler = require('express-async-handler')
const path = require('path')

const registerUser = errHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const { name, nickName, email, password, role, perk, registerCheckbox } = req.body;

    const user = await User.create({
        name,
        nickName,
        password,
        email,
        role,
        perk
    })

    if (!registerCheckbox) {
        res.status(400)
        .json({
            success:false
        })
    }

    res.status(201)
        .sendFile(path.resolve('./Views/register.html'))

})

module.exports = {
    registerUser
}
```

Even if it throws success false, I can't prevent to submit new registration and when I check DB, I see that it creates the new registration.

How can I prevent this situation in server side ? I am new in back end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if `registerCheckbox` is true **before** save the user in the database. It should be:

```
const User = require('../Models/User')
const errHandler = require('express-async-handler')
const path = require('path')

const registerUser = errHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const { name, nickName, email, password, role, perk, registerCheckbox } = req.body;

    // perform the verification
    if (!registerCheckbox) {
        res.status(400)
        .json({
            success:false
        });

       return; // I added the return here to stop the function when the verification is failed
    }

   // success case, add user in database
    const user = await User.create({
        name,
        nickName,
        password,
        email,
        role,
        perk
    })

    res.status(201)
        .sendFile(path.resolve('./Views/register.html'))

})

module.exports = {
    registerUser
}
```